# Save an image from a URL locally

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I currently have a plugin that pulls posts that I create on my blog using a RSS Feed to WordPress. The problem is its hotlinking my images. I want WordPress to save the images locally, then display them. Displaying the images I have no issue with.  This is the best I could find and tweaked it to my liking but it only crashes my website:

```
$data = my_get_remote_content('get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'enclosure', true )');
savePhoto(my_get_remote_content($data['body']), $post->ID); 

function my_get_remote_content($url) {
  $response = wp_remote_get($url, 
    array(
      'headers' => array(
        'user-agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2)'
      )
    )
  );
  if( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    throw new Exception('Error fetching remote content');
  } else {
    $data = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
    return $data;
  }  
}

function savePhoto($fileContents, $isbn) {
  if (DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR=='/'){
    $absolute_path = dirname(__FILE__).'/'; 
  } else { 
    $absolute_path = str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(__FILE__)).'/'; 
  }
  $newImg = imagecreatefromstring($fileContents);
  return imagejpeg($newImg, $absolute_path ."{$isbn}.jpg",100);
}
```

`get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'enclosure', true )` gets the actual link from my post meta data (custom fields) but I can't seem to make it work, can anyone help me out?
Thanks

Comment: what's happening now?

Comment: What errors are you getting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: my_get_remote_content(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'enclosure', true ));

Comment: I found that function here on stackoverflow, but I cant make it work. Im a newbie at both php and html, just started, thats why im asking for help at this

Comment: So - in order for us to help, you have to answer the questions we ask.  *What is happening now? What errors are you getting?*  Without that, helping is difficult at best.

Comment: If I add the code to my functions.php it does not give any blank error, if I add a img with src being $newImg it crashes my website